# Use MyDocuments in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I make these two lines of PowerShell into one:

```
$tmp=([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments"))
mkdir $tmp\foo\bar
```

PowerShell seamse to treat this as two lines if i try:

```
mkdir ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments"))\foo\bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use PowerShell cmdlets specially designed for that:

```
New-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) -ChildPath "foo\bar") -ItemType Directory -Force
```

Comment: Nice, thanks.
To people that come after, here is how to get the content of a file nested under MyDocuments: 
Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) -ChildPath "foo\bar.txt")